# Looking for non-GAUSS Code for Thiery Roncalli's book on Risk Parity and Budgeting

Tags: programming, risk-management, risk-parity

I am going through the book ['Introduction to Risk Parity and Budgeting'](http://www.thierry-roncalli.com/RiskParityBook.html) by Thierry Roncalli (2013). The author provides software for the various concepts illustrated in the book, but it is all done in GAUSS (see [here](http://www.thierry-roncalli.com/RiskParityBook.html#rpb-gauss)). It's a language I have never used and do not have access to.

I was wondering if someone would know of a Matlab, Python or even R repository that 'translates' at least partially the code? I tried looking for a Github repo that does it but couldn't find anything...

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Would VBA also be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this thesis which provide algebra and code in Matlab: https://research.cbs.dk/da/studentProjects/2ce27aba-d4df-4daa-b00e-1ea9a5e21049

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe this document only provides the high level MATLAB main program and not the sub-routines which do all the work.

Comment: You are not wrong @noob2, it just contains the main script which calls certain functions (just a couple) that are not visible. I don't mean to diss the answer at all though, I appreciate the effort, very much, it is just not quite what I am looking for. I am really surprised nobody has built a library out the book yet. The Gauss code is accessible and somehow readable, so it won't be impossibly hard to do. If one has access to the software itself , then of course it would be easier.